# Nested IF statement to ignore blanks (3)

Tags: excel

below is my logical expression which i am trying to resolve.

IF `A1=B2`, return `CONFLICT`

IF `B1=A2`, return`CONFLICT`

IF `A1, A2,B1, B2` are empty return nothing

Out of four cells if one of them having value and other 3 are blanks it should return nothing. I hope this explains clearly, currently below is the formulae that i am using.

```
=IF(A1="","",IF(A1=B2,"Conflict",IF(B1=A2,"Conflict","")))
```

Comment: "_currently below is the formulae that i am using_" - and what is the problem with it?

Comment: are you supposed to return something specific if all four a not empty and not a conflict case?

Answer (score 1):

Use AND and OR:

```
=IF(OR(A1="",A2="",B1="",B2="",AND(A1<>B2,B1<>A2)),"","Conflict")
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Edit:

If you want the pairs to be considered separately then use this:

```
=IF(AND(OR(A1="",B2="",A1<>B2),OR(B1="",A2="",B1<>A2)),"","Conflict")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for reply. But it didn't work. it is returning all blanks, though i got same string value in A1 and B2

Comment: scott shouldnt the last case be conflict?

Comment: @Raj works for me,  make sure the string values are the same and do not have spaces or other non printable characters that would make it look the same but not actually be the same

Comment: @ForwardEd no `IF A1, A2,B1, B2 are empty return nothing`

Comment: @ScottCraner I had read it as if they were all empty, not just one of them

Comment: Hi Forward, still it didn't work. if i have string value in A1 it is returning conflict, but i want blank.

Comment: @Raj are any of the pictures above returning the wrong output?  If so which and why?

Comment: @Scott, yeah i am entering one character in A1 still it is returning conflict.

Comment: @Raj I am not getting that, see last photo.  How are the data being filled in?  Are they formula?  If so is it returning `""` or `" "`?  Or are you blanking out the cells with a space and not a delete?  Try clearing all the cells by highlighting them and hitting delete, then put the values in one by one.

Comment: @Scott, yes your formulae working with numbers that you used in pictures, but if you try to put number 1 in A1 and 1 in B2 it is not returning conflict

Comment: @Raj I thought if any were blank it would return blank. see edit for independent.

Comment: @Scott, that's right if any where blank it should return blank, If A1 has value 1 and B2 has same value 1 it should return conflict and if A1 has value 1 and B1, B2,A2 are blank it should return blank,  If B1 has value 1 and A2 has same value 1 it should return conflict.